# Jquery AJAX to pure js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to change `JQuery` code to `JavaScript xhttp`.

This is my jQuery

```
var sendRequest = function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: urlIn, 
        data: dataIn,
        type: typeIn,
        success: funcSuccess,
        error: funcError,
    });
};
```

This is my JavaScript.

```
var sendRequest = function() {
 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        funcSuccess(this.responseText);
    }else{
        funcSuccess(this.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open(typeIn, urlIn, true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send(dataIn);   

}
```

It doesn't work.
What Am I miss?

Comment: Any error? Do you see anything in network tab in browser developer tools? What is `typeIn`, `urlIn` or `funcSucces()`?

Comment: why you have called funcSuccess in else block...?

Comment: syntax is true, TypeIn = POST, urlIn =  request.php, funcSuccess is callback function.
everything are for a AJAX Long polling, Just on JQuery function it work, but when I'm trying to change it on JavaScript, It dont work.

Comment: Maybe `this.status == 200` is `false`. The XHR is completely okay. I think it's the server's fault.

Comment: It is POST request, so it is possible that server responds with `201` code (201 created). But it doesn't matter since he has `funcSuccess` even on error :). Whole code is a mess. But without knowing errors, server response etc. we can't help him.